# Can z value in quaternion get negative?

Tags: transform, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm still learning kinematics like quaternion. The answer of [this QA page](http://answers.ros.org/question/740/quaternions-orientation-representation), which I thank the author for the complete explanation, describes as follows:

```
(x, y, z, w) = (0, 0, sin(theta/2), cos(theta/2))
```

That means I guess 0 < z < 1 (when 0 <= theta < 2pi). However, in the return value from `tf.TransformListener().lookupTransform` (in `C++`), z can often be negative. For example, using `turtleSim` on `RViz`, z value I see is -0.717892 when a turtle looks almost down or 6PM or 3pi/2. Am I wrong somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11790/can-z-value-in-quaternion-get-negative?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a rotation quaternion q=(x,y,z,w), then -q=(-x,-y,-z,-w) describes the same rotation, so you cannot rely on z (or any other component) being positive.

A rotation quaternion is essentially a rotation axis (x,y,z) and an amount of rotation w (I avoid the word angle because it's not an angle in the usual sense), scaled to unit length (|q|=1). If you change the sign of w, you reverse the rotation direction. The same thing happens if you mirror the rotation axis to (-x,-y,-z). So if you do both, these effects cancel each other out.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5